# Python text parsing between two words

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautifulsoup and want to extract all text from between two words on a webpage.

Ex, imagine the following website text:

```
This is the text of the webpage. It is just a string of a bunch of stuff and maybe some tags in between.
```

I want to pull out everything on the page that starts with `text` and ends with `bunch`.

In this case I'd want only:

```
text of the webpage. It is just a string of a bunch
```

However, there's a chance there could be multiple instances of this on a page.

What is the best way to do this?

This is my current setup:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mechanize import Browser
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

mech = Browser()
urls = [
http://ca.news.yahoo.com/forget-phoning-business-app-sends-text-instead-100143774--sector.html
    ]



   for url in urls:
        page = mech.open(url)
        html = page.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        text= soup.prettify()
            texts = soup.findAll(text=True) 

    def visible(element):
        if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title']: 
        # If the parent of your element is any of those ignore it

            return False

        elif re.match('<!--.*-->', str(element)):
        # If the element matches an html tag, ignore it

            return False

        else:
        # Otherwise, return True as these are the elements we need

          return True

    visible_texts = filter(visible, texts)
    # Filter only returns those items in the sequence, texts, that return True. 
    # We use those to build our final list.

    for line in visible_texts:
      print line
```

Answer (score 2):

since you're just parsing the text you just need the regex:

```
import re
result = re.findall("text.*?bunch", text_from_web_page)
```

Comment: Thanks but I have no idea the type of tag it will be in. What I have done is parsed out all the text so now this is more of a text parsing question. I've updated my code to show this.

Comment: what is `text_from_web_page` variable supposed to be in my example?

Comment: the text you extracted in this case: "This is the text of the webpage. It is just a string of a bunch of stuff and maybe some tags in between.
"